# GCPのロールが操作できるリソースのリストを知りたい

Tags: google-compute-engine

GCPでroles/editorやroles/compute.instanceAdminなどのロールが、それぞれどのリソースを操作できるかを知りたいと思っています。

APIでqueryGrantableRolesというメソッドがありますが、これはリソース名(or URI)を引数にとって、そのリソースを操作できるロールの一覧を出します。ちょうどこれの逆ができる操作を探しています。

ご存知でしたら教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。